# Why does my puppy smell like cookies in the morning?

Tags: dogs

Obviously this is not a complaint! I don't mind that she smells like cookies when I take her out of her crate in the morning (particularly when considering the other things she *could* smell like). The only things in her crate (plastic) at night are herself (7mo Finnish Lapphund), a Kong ring, and a Petstages cold chew. She sometimes smells like cookies when she wakes up from naps in her other crate (wire), too.

Why does she smell like cookies? And, is this normal?

Comment: What do you mean by cookies? Does your whole dog smell like that? Or just certain parts? Does her breath have a sweet smell?

Comment: Is it just your dog? Does the bedding have the same scent?

Comment: When she comes out at first I get a hint of cookie smell but then as she continues to sit in front of me to receive her morning cuddles the smell goes away. When she's not just been in her crate, I haven't ever smelled it. And her breath smells like not much of anything in the morning, then her food throughout the day. 

She doesn't have bedding because she is a serial fabric destroyer :)

Answer (score 2):

This is very interesting! I've never even heard of this, but I wanted to know why, so I did a little digging.

Let me start by saying you could and should talk to your vet about this if it's something you are concerned about.

According to [Doggysaurus.com](https://doggysaurus.com/why-do-dogs-smell-like-biscuits-digestives/#:%7E:text=Dogs)

> Dogs’ feet and ears can sometimes smell like digestive biscuits or
> cookies due to a build-up of yeast, Proteus bacteria, or Pseudomonas
> bacteria. All can develop in-between the toes of your dog where it’s
> warm, damp, and not a lot of air circulation.

There is more information in there as well if you want to dive a little further.